# How to change the order of label and icon within an actionButton in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, action-button

I have a "Next Page" actionButton within my shiny-app that has an arrow displayed as an icon and the words "Next Page". However, the icon always appears in front of the lable like this:

[image]

I want the icon to appear after the text, like it is normally done. I am using the code

```
hidden(actionButton(inputId = "Next", label = "Next Page", icon = icon("chevron-right"), width = "20%"))
```

Simply changing the order of the code does not work and I could not find any examples. I would appreciate any tipps, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `div` ton construct the icon after text:

```
actionButton(inputId = "Next", label = div("Next Page", icon("chevron-right")), width = "20%")
```

Comment: I am using this method for a button with "caret-down". I would like to change it to "caret-up" once I have clicked on it. `updateActionButton(session, 'mybutton', label = div('Label', icon = 'caret-up'))` (simplifying here) but that's not working. Any idea why?

Comment: Please post a new question. Have a look at conditionnalPanel based on value of button